# Roslaunch and env variables for HOSTNAME

Tags: ros, roslaunch, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my launch file I want to read the hostname from user input and when it is missing, it will use the local hostname by default.
I use this line in my launch file

```
<arg name="hostname" default="$(env HOSTNAME)" />
```

When doing `echo $HOSTNAME` in the terminal, the value is set, however when I run roslaunch it complains that there is no HOSTNAME variable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240401/roslaunch-and-env-variables-for-hostname/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2016-07-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HOSTNAME is a special environment variable that is not available for shell scripts.
adding

```
export HOSTNAME
```

to my .bashrc fixed the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4